# c# convert ObservableCollection to another type

Tags: c#, inheritance, type-conversion, observablecollection

I have the following problem that has got me stuck. In the below example I'm creating class A and class B and inheriting class A from class B. I then create an `ObservableCollection<A>` to hold a collection of people. What I then wish to do is expand class A to include the properties in class B and create this as a referenced copy ObservableCollection which I can update.

The error I'm getting when this complies is:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   `'<CastIterator>d__b1'1[iheriatance_obseravale_collection.Form1+B]'` to
>   type
>   `'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection'1[iheriatance_obseravale_collection.Form1+B]'`.

```
public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _firstName;
    public string firstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_firstName != value)
            {
                _firstName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("firstName");
            }
        }
    }

    string _surname;
    public string surname
    {
        get
        {
            return _surname;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_surname != value)
            {
                _surname = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("surname");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string PropName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropName));
        }
    }
}

public class B : A, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool _isSelected;
    public bool isSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected != value)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("isSelected");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string PropName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropName));
        }
    }
}

ObservableCollection<A> peopleColl = new ObservableCollection<A>();

private void addData()
{
    peopleColl.Add(new A() { firstName = "James", surname = "Smith" });
    peopleColl.Add(new A() { firstName = "John", surname = "Woods" });
}

ObservableCollection<B> selectedPeople;

private void selectAllPeople()
{
    selectedPeople = (ObservableCollection<B>)peopleColl.Cast<B>();

    foreach (B person in selectedPeople)
    {
        person.isSelected = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Surname:{0}, IsSelected:{1}", person.surname, person.isSelected);
    }
}
```

Many thanks
Stuart Turbefield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate the source, cast each object, then create a new collection :

```
 selectedPeople = new ObservableCollection<B>(peopleColl.OfType<B>());
```

this works only if peopleColl contains `B` objects. If it contains only `A`, you need to create new instances of `B` from `A` :

```
 selectedPeople = new ObservableCollection<B>(peopleColl.Select(i => new B(i));

public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
    }

    public B(A a)
    {
       this.firstName = a.firstName;
       this.surname = a.surname;
    }
}
```

Just for info, if `A` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and if `B` inherits from `A`, there's no need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` again in the `B` class.